# How can I check the values of a webelement in a selenium test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am developing a selenium test for my SpringBoot application and I have managed to create a new account, create a new project on that account and give it a value of funds=0, then I donated money to that project, and redirect to the page which shows a users contributions including 'amountContributed' element which has the value > 0 as the donation was made.

How do I check the value of an element in Selenium test? My attempt is below and the error I got is below that:

//Redirects to the users contributions page.
assertEquals("Your Contributions", this.webDriver.getTitle());

```
    //Assert that the total contributed amount for the project is 2000 as it was 0 prior to contribution.
    assertEquals("2000", this.webDriver.findElement(By.id("amountContributed")));


expected: <2000> but was: <[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (60e2cb3895ae1f8e300b2068bd0f46c7)] -> id: amountContributed]>
```

HTML :

```
<span>Amount Contributed: </span>
<li th:text="${project.amountContributed}" id="amountContributed">Amount Contributed</li>
```

Comment: Add the selenium code you tried that resulted in the error.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
this.webDriver.findElement(By.id("amountContributed"))
```

will return a web element, and you are comparing a **web element** with string **"2000"**. and that's the reason you are getting the below exception :

> expected: <2000> but was: <[[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS
> (60e2cb3895ae1f8e300b2068bd0f46c7)] -> id: amountContributed]>

try this instead :

```
assertEquals("2000", this.webDriver.findElement(By.id("amountContributed")).getText());
```

But the HTML that you've shared :

```
<span>Amount Contributed: </span>
<li th:text="${project.amountContributed}" id="amountContributed">Amount Contributed</li>
```

shows that if you use `amountContributed` as a id, `.getText()` would return

```
Amount Contributed
```

string, and your assertion will fail again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think that might work though because although the text says Amount Contributed, on the actual web page it displays 2000. Does the 'Amount Contributed' text in the <li> element not get overwritten by the 2000? Thanks again.

Comment: It depends on the user interaction that could change the DOM. Was it helpful ?if yes, can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this. –